# Getting ordered items from core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Lets say I have a core data model, and my objects have date and some other attribute. The other attribute can hold yes or no.

What would be the best way to get the newest item by date, and then get each item older until I hit the first one set to no (where yes is the norm).

```
So object 1 has Feb 22, 2011 and yes
object 2 has Feb 21, 2011 and yes
object 3 has Feb 18, 2011 and yes
object 4 has Feb 11, 2011 and yes
object 5 has Feb 10, 2011 and no
object 6 has Feb 9, 2011 and yes
object 7 has Feb 1, 2011 and no
```

I want to get at 1-5, and stop retrieving items.

I've used indexPath.row+1 inside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but that won't work in this case.

A push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont exactly get your Question but for sorting the array use NSSortDescriptor like ...

```
{   
    NSSortDescriptor* descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    sortedValues = [[allValues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]] retain];    
}
```

...you can use ascending: YES or NO according to your requirement and this situation (which you describe it should be NO).Also don't forget to rename the key @"date" to the one you have in your databese.

If you want to get only those data form database which has YES in the second field try add a NSPredicate like this .......

```
{   
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    CoreDataModel* delegate = [CoreDataModel sharedInstance];

    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourTableName" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.secondFieldName == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

    NSArray* arr = [[delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];   
}
```

Comment: I got so used to using an NSFetchedResultsController for tables that I forgot you could do a fetch and get an array already sorted. Thanks!

Comment: -1: This sort and predicate will return all objects whose `secondField==YES` but it won't stop the fetch upon hitting the first `NO`. He will get objects 1,2,3,4,6 when he just wants 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: You're right, it won't. But the fact that I can execute a sorted fetch and get an array solved my specific issue (though not how I worded my question). In my app, getting every entry into an array and writing my own logic to stop at NO works fine. In an app with expected larger database sizes, this approach wouldn't work. I don't expect anyone not testing to ever have over 5000 items in my app.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is actually fairly difficult because it requires logic that is aware of the entire state of the data. That is not something a simple predicate or sort can accomplish.

A predicate just looks for all objects whose own attributes that match a particular set of condition test. All objects passing the test are returned by the predicate. A predicate cannot compare two objects and it especially cannot compare all objects to figure out what order they should be in.

A sort will sort all the objects given and can't exclude any.

You have to provide the logic to find the first `NO` by some means other than predicates and sorts. You can either provide the logic in the code associated with the fetch or include it in the data model itself.

(1) With the fetch code: Use two fetches. First, fetch all objects whose `otherAttribute==NO` and sort by date descending. The first object, object-5 in the OP example, in the returned array will be the most recent `NO`.

Then take the date of the first object and use that to create a predicate for the second fetch `otherAttribute==NO AND date>firstNoDate`. That will return (1,2,3,4) in the example in the OP.

Merge the two returned arrays and sort on date to get the array (1,2,3,4,5).

(2) Create a linked data structure in the entity model itself so that you entity looks like:

```
MyEntity{
    date:date
    otherAttribute:Bool
    previousByDate<-(optional)->MyEntity.next
    nextByDate<-(optional)->MyEntity.previous
}
```

When you add objects to the object graph, you will have to fetch the object with the previous date and then insert the new object in appropriate place.

To use this, do a fetch object whose `previousByDate==nil` then walk the `nextByDate` until you find one whose `otherAttribute==NO`.

Use the first method if the ordering and sorting are only for the UI and they have no relevance to the data model itself. Use the second method if the ordering is necessary to model the data in the first place.